# Rare earth minerals in solarcell production

Tags: renewable-energy, solar-cells

When I was looking at photovoltaic solar cell production I saw that there was some difficulty with rare earth minerals used in the production but i can't find which rare earth  minerals. I have tried to look around the web but i can't find anything specific.

What kind of rare earth minerals are used in solar cell productions?

Source:
http://www.c2es.org/technology/factsheet/solar (MId way down the page)

Comment: Could you cite the source?

Comment: http://www.c2es.org/technology/factsheet/solar

About half way down the page unde "Obstacles to Further Development and Deployment of Solar Power" then under "Cost"

Comment: The two sources the page quotes say that China put quotas on rare earths (true) http://www.reuters.com/assets/print?aid=USTRE77219A20110803 and that rare earths are important for solar cell *research* (true) http://www.denverpost.com/news/ci_17108810

Answer (score 1):

Rare earth elements aren't really used much in PV at all. The market is dominated by silicon cells (~95% of the market). The next big player is Cadmium Telluride (~5% of the market). The rest are pretty insignificant.

Also, note that rare-earth elements are (with the exception of Promethium) not particularly rare.

Answer (score 0):

The major one is Indium. [Indium Tin Oxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_tin_oxide) is used as a transparent conductive electrode used to coat the top of the cell. Indium production is a potential bottleneck when it comes to expansion of the PV manufacturing industry and currently costs around $700/kg. Less than [1000 tonnes per year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium#Production) is produced. However, it looks like it may well be replaced with carbon in the form of [Graphene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene).

Comment: Indium isn't a rare earth element though, is it?

Comment: Maybe the OP is confused with the possible shortage of Neodymium used in wind turbine generators